# Vue with Router. Making multiple pages

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, tailwind-css, vue-router

I honestly don't know how to title this. But here are the details.
I have a Vue project with Router. I am very new to Router.

App.vue contains just <RouterView> I don't think it needs any more explanation.

First page is LoginView.vue - very simple login pop up to prevent access before going into the site.

Once logged in, it goes into HomeView.vue
In HomeView.vue I would like it to display some stuff. For example: About page, Contact page, etc.

First of all did I organise this right.
Views > LoginView.vue
Views > HomeView.vue > components > About.vue or Contact.vue.
Or is it supposed to be :
Components > HomePage.vue > Views > AboutView.vue or ContactView.vue

Secondly, how can I get ether contact or about to show up in my home page without having to copy everything in the home page to my about or contacts tab.

App.vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { RouterView } from 'vue-router'

</script>

<template>
  <body>
    <div>
      <RouterView />
    </div>
  </body>
</template>
```

Views > LoginView.vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { RouterLink } from 'vue-router'
</script>

<template>
<body>
    <div class="flex justify-center items-center h-screen bg-woodsmoke-950">
        <div class="w-96 p-6 shadow-lg bg-white rounded-md">
            <h1 class="block text-3xl text-center font-arial font-bold">Welcome</h1>
            <div class="mt-1">
                <p class="text-woodsmoke-400 text-center">Login Here!</p>
            </div>
            <hr class="mt-3">
            <div class="mt-3">
                <lable for="username" class="block text-base mb-2">Username</lable>
                <input type="text" id="username" class="border w-full text-base px-2 py-1 focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 focus:border-gray-600" placeholder="Enter Username...">
            </div>
            <div class="mt-3">
                <lable for="password" class="block text-base mb-2">Password</lable>
                <input type="text" id="password" class="border w-full text-base px-2 py-1 focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 focus:border-gray-600" placeholder="Enter Password...">
            </div>
            <div class="mt-3 flex justify-between items-center">
                <div>
                    <input type="checkbox">
                    <label>Remember Me?</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <RouterLink to="/home" class="border-2 border-vred-700 bg-vred-50 text-vred-700 py-1 px-5 rounded-md hover:bg-vred-100 hover:text-vred-700 hover:border-vred-700">Login</RouterLink>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</template>
```

Views > HomeView.vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { RouterLink, RouterView } from 'vue-router'
</script>

<template>
  <Body class="h-screen bg-woodsmoke-950">
    <header class="flex justify-between h-max bg-black">
      <RouterLink to="/home" class="flex justify-start items-center text-7xl text-vred-900 font-arial font-bold border-r-4 border-vred-950 my-1 ml-7 pr-3"
      >Title</RouterLink>

      <div class="flex justify-end items-center my-1 mr-7">
        <RouterLink to="/contactMe" class="text-md text-vred-400 font-arial font-bold bg-vred-950 rounded-xl p-1">Contact Me</RouterLink>
      </div>
      </header>

    <main>
      <RouterView></RouterView> <!-- This is where about will show up by default but would be replaced with contact me -->
    </main>
  </Body>
</template>
```

Indext.ts

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import LoginView from '../views/LoginView.vue'

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'login',
      component: LoginView
    },
    {
      path: '/home',
      name: 'home',
      component: () => import('../views/HomeView.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'about',
      component: () => import('../components/About.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/contact_me',
      name: 'contactMe',
      component: () => import('../components/ContactMe.vue')
    }
  ]
})

export default router
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the file organization is up to you. There's no objectively correct way to do it. Do what makes the most sense to you.

Second, having `<router-view>` inside another `<router-view>` is how you set up nested routes, which it sounds like is what you want. The [Vue Router documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html#Nested-Routes) explains nested routes very well so please read it first.

Basically, the about and contactMe routes will need to be placed within a `children` property on the home route. Then depending on the combination of parent + child path the `<router-view>` in the HomeView component will be replaced with either the About component or contactMe component. To show the About component by default, you would leave it's child route path as empty.

```js
routes: [
  {
    path: '/home',
    name: 'home',
    component: () => import('../views/HomeView.vue')
    children: [
      {
        // path of /home will display 'home' component with 'about' nested by default
        path: '',
        name: 'about',
        component: () => import('../components/About.vue')
      },
      // path of /home/contact_me will display 'home' component with nested 'contactMe'
      {
        path: 'contact_me',
        name: 'contactMe',
        component: () => import('../components/ContactMe.vue')
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the speedy response, linking the document, the details and solving something I was stuck at!!